# How to set classpath for lucene jar files

Tags: java, apache, jar, lucene, classpath

I am using Lucene and trying to set the classpath for the four jar files as mentioned in the Lucene 5.0.0 demo API
"You need four JARs: the Lucene JAR, the queryparser JAR, the common analysis JAR, and the Lucene demo JAR.

Put all four of these files in your Java CLASSPATH.

I am trying to set classpath variable by entering the following variable value in classpath environment variable 
"F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\core; F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\queryparser; F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\analysis\common; F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\demo;

but whenever I run the following command:
java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs {path-to-lucene}/src

I get the error message "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.lucene.IndexFiles".

How can I sort out this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you've added to the classpath isn't correct.  Either add the jars directly, as in the [instructions of the IndexFiles demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/demo/overview-summary.html#Setting_your_CLASSPATH):

> F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\core\lucene-core-5.0.0.jar; ...

Or add the whole directory with a wildcard (see [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)):

> F:\Academic\KAU_ResearchGroups\PlagiarismDetection\Lucene\lucene-5.0.0\core\*; ...

Answer (score -1):

You should never trust them, upload previous versions, When I worked with Lucene I always had this type of errors  so I uploaded all lucen versions from the first one till the last(lucen1.9, lucene 2......, Lucene 3.3, lucene 4) and I added them as jars and till now I don't know which one had  resolved the problem ;)
 don't worry about the difference between the declaration of functions when you use them, you can use the version like this
Query q = new QueryParser(**Version.LUCENE_40**, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);

good luck

Comment: Having mismatched lucene versions in your classpath is a likely *cause* of errors.  The fact that you resolved an issue by installing a bunch of old versions of lucene is positively puzzling.  Passing an older version into a method call using something like `Version.LUCENE_40` instructs it to use compatibility logic built into your *current* version of lucene, not to load up old jars on your classpath.  Doesn't work like that.